# System.Web in .NET Standard Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I am trying to port our existing `.NET 4.6.1` class library to `.NET Standard 2.1`.
Most of the dependencies are resolved. However I am unsure what to do with the `System.Web.Configuration`.
Our current code has something like this:

```
config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
```

- How to include the dependency with System.Web.Configuration to my project?
- How to change the code to remove this dependency?

Comment: as quick comment, System.Web is completely out of scope in .NET core / standard, so the solution will be to change code.

Comment: I think you'll need to replace that entire bit with custom written code, unless there's already some nuget package to take care of it. The configuration, as was done through web.config, is no more in ASP.NET core.

Comment: The *configuration* system is completely different too, so `WebConfigurationManager` wouldn't return anything. In .NET Core (not just ASP.NET Core), you can load settings from *multiple* sources, generate concrete config objects and inject them through Dependency Injection. This makes testing a *LOT* easier too - if you want to test a controller, just create an object on the fly and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: .NET Core's configuration is explained in [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You need to understand how configuration works now to decide how to modify your application, how to structure settings, what kinds of setting sections you need, what objects etc. Also how to *override* settings on different environments - XDT transformations have been replaced too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the valuable comments. I have a followup question. Since this is a class library applications using Full .NET Framework as well as Applications using .NET CORE will use this library. In that case How do I support this?

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` is a .NET Standard package. It can be used by both runtimes. You shouldn't be trying to read the web config directly anyway, the current library should receive its configuration settings from the client code as concrete objects. Simply removing the hard-coded config access would allow your library to work with both runtimes. After all, why should .NET Framework users have to use *your* web.config layout? Why prevent them from loading settings eg from a database?

Comment: Once you remove the hard-coded web.config access, you can create a "helper" library for .NET Framework to read from `web.config`, generate the objects and possibly inject them

Answer (score 2):

System.Web.Configuration is not part of .netstandard / .netcore. For a web application, the configuration is not done on a web.config anymore, but on an appsettings.json (with possibilities to have environment specific configurations).

Instead of using System.Web.Configuration, you should use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. The IConfiguration interface represents by default the configuration of your website and can be injected into your services.

Comment: `IConfiguration` *shouldn't* be injected out-of-hand. It's better to inject strongly typed config objects instead of taking a direct dependency on the configuration system

Comment: Agree on that. My point was more to explain how the configuration was working in .netcore in comparison with .net framework